# how to prove the laplace transform of time advanced version of signal is e^+st * F(S)?

Tags: laplace-transform

how to prove the laplace transform of time advanced version of signal is e^+st * F(S) ?

Comment: What does "time advanced version of signal" mean?

Comment: i.e if f(t) has a laplace transform  F(S), what is the laplace transform of f(t+to) , ( time advanced version ), now in this case Laplace transform will be  e^+sto * F(S).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have that:

$$\mathscr{L}_t\left[\text{f}\left(t-\alpha\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}:=\int_0^\infty\text{f}\left(t-\alpha\right)\cdot e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t\tag1$$

Substitute $\text{u}=t-\alpha$:

$$\mathscr{L}_t\left[\text{f}\left(t-\alpha\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\int_{-\alpha}^\infty\text{f}\left(\text{u}\right)\cdot e^{-\text{s}\left(\text{u}+\alpha\right)}\space\text{d}\text{u}=e^{-\alpha\text{s}}\int_{-\alpha}^\infty\text{f}\left(\text{u}\right)\cdot e^{-\text{s}\text{u}}\space\text{d}\text{u}\tag2$$

When $\Re\left(\text{s}\right)>0$

**EDIT:**

When $\alpha<0$:

$$\mathscr{L}_t\left[\text{f}\left(t+\alpha\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=e^{\alpha\text{s}}\int_\alpha^\infty\text{f}\left(\text{u}\right)\cdot e^{-\text{s}\text{u}}\space\text{d}\text{u}\tag2$$

Comment: Yup, in the above case, we need to consider a function which is defined for only positive values of t, then only we get e−αs F(s), I am able to prove this for f(t−α), the problem is with f(t+α),

Comment: @suryakrishna No, we can set $\alpha$ equal to a real value which is smaller than $0$, so we get for example: $$\text{f}\left(t-\left(-4\right)\right)=\text{f}\left(t+4\right)$$

Comment: Yes, in that case, the limit changes to -(-4) --> i,e the new limit will be from +4 to Infinity, but not from 0 to Infinity. getting it ?

Comment: @suryakrishna Of cource I understand, so your statement (claim) in your question is wrong! Because the lower bound of the integral (which is the definition of the Laplace transform) change

Comment: Question is absolutely correct, not sure of how to prove it !?

Comment: @suryakrishna It isn't because the lower bound change. If you are so sure, than you will also be able to prove me wrong and yourself right!

Comment: f(t) has a laplace transfrom of F(S)
how to prove f(t−(−4)) has a laplace transform as e^+4s F(S).

Actually it is a standard result , I am unable to prove the same.

Comment: @suryakrishna Let's try an example. We set $\text{f}\left(t\right)=\sin\left(t\right)$: $$\mathscr{L}_t\left[\sin\left(t+4\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=e^{4\text{s}}\int_4^\infty\sin\left(\text{u}\right)\cdot e^{-\text{s}\text{u}}\space\text{d}\text{u}=\frac{\cos\left(4\right)+\text{s}\cdot\sin\left(4\right)}{1+\text{s}^2}\ne$$
$$e^{4\text{s}}\int_0^\infty\sin\left(\text{u}\right)\cdot e^{-\text{s}\text{u}}\space\text{d}\text{u}=\frac{e^{4\text{s}}}{1+\text{s}^2}$$

Comment: @suryakrishna So, you're wrong!

Comment: Cool, thanks for the example, may be the book which i am referring to have stated it wrongly.

Comment: @suryakrishna Well, you see that I did, and your method gives a very wrong result!

Comment: Yes, completely agree. its a mistake in the book which i am referring. :)